# Statistical test on percentage data with replicates

Tags: t-test, proportion

Imagine I am doing an experiment where I want to look at the cellular composition of tumour samples

I have 3 samples with phenotype A (e.g. metastasizing) and 3 samples with phenotype B (e.g. not metastasizing)

The samples with phenotype A consist of (respectively) 30%, 32% and 33% "green cells", 28%, 27% and 28% "blue cells" and 42%, 41% and 39% "red cells".

The samples with phenotype B consist of (respectively) 10, 9 and 11 "green cells", 50%, 49% and 47% "blue cells" and 40%, 42% and 42% "red cells".

How can I tell if there is a significantly different % of the different cell types between the different types tumours (e.g. between phenotypes)?

Normally it would require 3 t-tests. However because they are %s, I suppose that the assumptions of a t-test are not met. Is there an analogous test for %s?

Comment: Jim, there is currently a discussion on a very similar question [here](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/Repeated-measures-analysis-of-fractions-summing-to-a-constant-tp5719257.html); you might take interest.

Answer (score 5):

The difficulty with doing three t-tests is that one of the null hypotheses is redundant: if we know there is no difference between phenotypes in the proportions of green and blue cells then there can also be no difference between phenotypes in the proportion of red cells, otherwise the proportions would not add up to 1. Solutions are typically based on the log of the relative proportions, i.e. the log of the ratio of the proportion of red cells and green cells, and the log of the ratio of the proportion of blue cells and green cells. This still leaves two strategies: one can model the average proportions, but transform those averages to log relative proportions or one can transform the variables and model the mean log relative proportions.

One way to perform the test following the first strategy would be to assume that these proportions are from a [Dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution), fit the parameters of this distribution with maximum likelihood while allowing those parameters to differ by phenotype, and than test whether those parameters are the same using a Wald test. In Stata this could be done with [dirifit](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s456725.html). See the example below:

```
. // enter the data
. drop _all

. 
. input ///
> phen green blue red

         phen      green       blue        red
 1. 1    .3    .28  .42 
 2. 1    .32   .27  .41 
 3. 1    .33   .28  .39
 4. 2    .10   .50  .40
 5. 2    .09   .49  .42
 6. 2    .11   .47  .42
 7. end

. 
. // test based a Dirichlet distribution
. dirifit green blue red, mu(phen) nolog

ML fit of Dirichlet (mu, phi)                     Number of obs   =          6
                                                  Wald chi2(2)    =     867.56
Log likelihood =  38.955704                       Prob > chi2     =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
mu2          |
        phen |   1.717543   .0583315    29.44   0.000     1.603215     1.83187
       _cons |  -1.851818   .0841125   -22.02   0.000    -2.016675    -1.68696
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
mu3          |
        phen |   1.169845   .0570941    20.49   0.000     1.057942    1.281747
       _cons |  -.9195806   .0794159   -11.58   0.000    -1.075233   -.7639284
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     /ln_phi |   7.518719   .4081268    18.42   0.000     6.718805    8.318633
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         phi |   1842.206   751.8535                      827.8277    4099.551
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mu2 = blue
mu3 = red


base outcome = green

. test [mu2]_b[phen] = [mu3]_b[phen] = 0

( 1)  [mu2]phen - [mu3]phen = 0
( 2)  [mu2]phen = 0

          chi2(  2) =  867.56
        Prob > chi2 =    0.0000
```

An alternative and related approach which still follows the first strategy would be to estimate a fractional multinomial logit using maximum quasi-likelihood followed by a Wald test. In Stata this could be done with [fmlogit](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s456976.html).

```
. // test based on a fractional multinomial logit
. fmlogit green blue red, eta(phen) nolog

ML fit of fractional multinomial logit            Number of obs   =          6
                                                  Wald chi2(2)    =     670.05
Log pseudolikelihood = -6.0943944                 Prob > chi2     =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
eta_blue     |
        phen |   1.717445   .0697378    24.63   0.000     1.580762    1.854129
       _cons |  -1.852482    .085893   -21.57   0.000    -2.020829   -1.684135
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
eta_red      |
        phen |    1.16894   .0690569    16.93   0.000     1.033591    1.304289
       _cons |  -.9187959   .1022304    -8.99   0.000    -1.119164    -.718428
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. test [eta_blue]_b[phen] = [eta_red]_b[phen] = 0

 ( 1)  [eta_blue]phen - [eta_red]phen = 0
 ( 2)  [eta_blue]phen = 0

           chi2(  2) =  670.05
         Prob > chi2 =    0.0000
```

Alternatively, one could follow the second strategy and first transform the variables to log relative proportions and than model model those. This is a strategy proposed by Aitchison (1986[2003]). In Stata that would look like this:

```
. gen blue_green = ln( blue / green )

. 
. gen red_green = ln( red / green )

. 
. manova blue_green red_gree = phen

                           Number of obs =       6

                           W = Wilks' lambda      L = Lawley-Hotelling trace
                           P = Pillai's trace     R = Roy's largest root  

                  Source |  Statistic     df   F(df1,    df2) =   F   Prob>F
              -----------+--------------------------------------------------
                    phen | W   0.0074      1     2.0     3.0   201.29 0.0006 e
                         | P   0.9926            2.0     3.0   201.29 0.0006 e
                         | L 134.1916            2.0     3.0   201.29 0.0006 e
                         | R 134.1916            2.0     3.0   201.29 0.0006 e
                         |--------------------------------------------------
                Residual |                 4
              -----------+--------------------------------------------------
                   Total |                 5
              --------------------------------------------------------------
                           e = exact, a = approximate, u = upper bound on F
```

The difference between the two strategies is mainly whether one wants to investigate the relationship among the proportions or the relationship between the proportions and a set of explanatory variables. The challenge when investigating the relationship among proportions is that independence cannot mean a correlation of zero; if the proportion of red cells increases the proportion of other cells has to decrease, otherwise the proportions would no longer add up to 1. So independence means a negative correlation among proportions. The Dirichlet distribution assumes such independence: the proportions are negatively correlated, but only to the extend necessary to fulfill the "mechanical" requirement that proportions add up to 1. The fractional multinomial logit explicitly does not model this correlation among the proportions and solely focuses on the average proportions. So neither model is suited when studying the relationship among proportions. The problem with the second strategy is that in that case one models the mean log relative proportion, rather than the proportions. This makes the interpretation of the model, e.g. the computation of marginal effects, a lot harder than it is in the first strategy. So there are valid uses for both strategies, it just (as always) depends on the research question which one is most useful. My interpretation of the OP is that is closer to a problem fit for the first strategy than the second.

J. Aitchison (1986 [2003]) The Statistical Analysis of Compositional Data. Caldwell, NJ: The Blackburn Press.

Comment: Maarten, [here](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/Repeated-measures-analysis-of-fractions-summing-to-a-constant-tp5719257.html) is currently a discussion of a question very similar to the OP. Some people there argue that usual RM ANOVA will do. What  might be your opinion?

Comment: @ttnphns : I edited my answer to include the discussion you refered to .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem description correctly, I would use a multinomial regression model with a binary indicator for whether the sample was from cells of type A or B. Because we would be interested in whether there were any difference in any proportion of cells of any type, we want to treat the outcome as fully categorical. The null hypothesis for the Wald test or maximum liklihood test for the parameter associated with the indicator is that there is no difference in proportion of cell types between metastasized and non-metastasized cell samples. This test is analogous to a Pearson chi-square test 2 by K for contingency tables, but accounts for the fact that a single replicate contributes some proportion to the K categorical outcomes. In this case, K is three.

It would be a useful secondary analysis to describe specifically what the distribution of cells are and how you would hope to make a biomarker or other useful diagnostic model for metastasis.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try resampling (with replacement)?

Example: Combine your 6 samples into two. One sample for A with m data points, and one sample for B with n data points. Compute your percentages.

Now simulate a large number of samples with replacement, where you choose randomly from all (m+n) data points, and you again choose samples of size m and n.

Count up the number of samples that produce test statistics that match or are more extreme than your observed value.

The p-value is the ratio of the count in the previous step over the number of resamples.